# How does electrolarynx work?

Tags: human-biology, homework, cancer, biomedical-technology

I have heard that this is an effective replacement for patients who have a dysfunctional larynx, partly due to cancer.

I am curious to know the inner working of this device and why such a robotic voice comes out?
What is the basic principle of this device. Does it simply captures vibrations and converts it to sound? Just like how a mic does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your vocal chords vibrate to produce a tone, but your mouth shapes that tone into the sounds that make up voice. If your vocal chords fail or are removed, the electrolarynx can be used to vibrate the throat for you, but your mouth still needs to shape that sound into words. Because the electrolarynx produces a mechanical buzzing vibration, you get mechanical buzzing words. This is similar to how the talkbox works with electric guitars, the guitar sound is piped through a tube into the musicians mouth, they have to shape that sound into words with their mouth. Go listen to Peter Frampton for a good example.